# Stuck in endless loop when not dispatching an action in ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using Angular2 and ngrx/store and ngrx/effects for state management.

When a certain action fails I want to show an error message but it seems that I can't perform this task in an `@Effects()` block. See the following:

```
  @Effect() selectOfficeFail$ = this.actions$
   .ofType(SelectOfficeActions.LOAD_FAIL)
   .do(() => {
     alert('Error! No offices found!'); // I keep entering here
  });
```

When the code above runs the alert is run endless number of times until the browser crashes. It seems an `@Effect()` **has to** return a new `dispatch()` but I don't understand why. And why does the alert() above run endless number of times?

**Edit:** I am **not** dispatching `SelectOfficeActions.LOAD_FAIL` multiple times. Only once

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[UPDATE]
Now the best way to do that is to use `dispatch` option like this:

```js
@Effect({dispatch: false}) selectOfficeFail$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SelectOfficeActions.LOAD_FAIL)
    .do(() => {
        alert('Error! No offices found!'); // I keep entering here
    });
```

It means "reacts to this action but don't send another".

Comment: Best solution out there.

Comment: with Angular and Store >= 7, I needed to do `... this.actions$.pipe(ofType(SelectOfficeActions.LOAD_FAIL), tap(()=>{ alert('no offices'); });`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `do` allows the action to flow through your effect and the action is then dispatched, again, by the store. You could use `filter` to prevent that from happening:

```
@Effect() selectOfficeFail$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(SelectOfficeActions.LOAD_FAIL)
  .do(() => {
    alert('Error! No offices found!'); // I keep entering here
  })
  .filter(() => false);
```

Answer (score 3):

if using `createEffect` function then the `dispatch: false` flag needs to be passed as config parameter ([ngrx.io reference](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/createEffect))

```
effectName$ = createEffect(
  () => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(FeatureActions.actionOne),
    tap(() => console.log('Action One Dispatched'))
  ),
  { dispatch: false }
  // FeatureActions.actionOne is not dispatched
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're right the `@effect` needs to dispatch a new action, but i think there is something wrong in your application logic.

You shouldn't be dispatching the `SelectOfficeActions.LOAD_FAIL` action in a component or service but rather a a LOAD action which invokes an `@Effect` and the effect in turn dispatches a `LOAD_COMPLETE` or `LOAD_FAIL` based on the criteria.

Something like this [example](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) from the libraries github

```
 @Effect() login$ = this.updates$
      // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
      .whenAction('LOGIN')
      // Map the payload into JSON to use as the request body
      .map(update => JSON.stringify(update.action.payload))
      .switchMap(payload => this.http.post('/auth', payload)
        // If successful, dispatch success action with result
        .map(res => ({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: res.json() }))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
        .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED' }));
      );
```